# What should the input voltage be for a L7805CV voltage regulator?

Tags: voltage-regulator, datasheet

I've been looking through [the datasheet](http://www.st.com/internet/com/TECHNICAL_RESOURCES/TECHNICAL_LITERATURE/DATASHEET/CD00000444.pdf) and see the maximum input voltage rating, but nowhere do I see a *minimum* input voltage rating. Is that information in there and I'm just missing it? What's the minimum input voltage that can be used with this voltage regulator?

Comment: A related [question](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/7463/7812-minimum-input-voltage)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Look at chapter 5 under line regulation.

For the 5V regulator at \$V_{IN} = 7 V\$, then you will typically see a \$3 mV\$ ripple with varying load, up to \$50 mV\$ worst case. At \$V_{IN} = 8 V\$ this reduces to \$1 mV\$ typical and \$25 mV\$ worst case.

So you'll need at least \$2V\$ head room, but \$3V\$ has less ripple (which is better)

Another parameter to look at is Dropout Voltage, which is just little below the line regulation. The dropout voltage is the voltage required for the regulator (between output and input) to be able to do its job properly.  In the same table is stated typically \$V_{d} = 2V\$. But if you want to design a robust circuit, you should always use the worst case which is here \$V_{d,max} = 2.5 V\$ value to ensure the circuit will work with all regulators.

Answer (score 9):

Others have pointed you to the *dropout voltage* parameter. Forget the typical value, the worst case (in this case the maximum) is the only relevant figure.

An don't forget

- that this is the voltage above the output voltage, which is (again worst case) 5.2V.
- that the input must never be below this level, so if you have a transformer, bridge and capacitor before it you must calculate the lowest value of the ripple, not the average or top.

Comment: Can we turn down the jargon a bit? This is a teaching website serving an international audience, so please, whenever possible, use plain language, not cutesy insider shorthand.

Comment: @dave: which 'we' and which jargon words? Keep in mind that I am not a native English speaker, technical English is the bulk of English I read.

Comment: 'elco' is Dutch for 'electrolytic capacitor'. I remember stevenvh once mentioning a better abbreviation for it, but I can't remember it right now.

Comment: I was not aware of that. Changed.

Comment: Also I haven't actually seen word trafo used for transformer in English before, but I could be wrong.

Comment: Changed. Transformer feels like the cartoon character to me, but I'll adjust to the rest of the world.

Comment: What if we now in advance that our circuit is going to use a relatively low maximum current, in which case the dropout voltage (both typical and worst case maximum, I assume) will be lower? Some regulators (e.g. MCP1700) has 0 dropout at 0 current, and it goes up linearly. So if we expect to draw no more than 25% of regulator's rated current, can't we use the worst case maximum dropout voltage at this current for our calculations? MCP1700's datasheet says "The minimum VIN must meet two conditions: VIN >= 2.3V and VIN >= VR + 3.0% + VDROPOUT". The extra 3%, I assume, is for good regulation.

Comment: You can take liberties with the datasheet, but at your own risk. Extrapolating properties of one component to another is risky. The MCP1700 has a pass-P-mosfet, which has a current-dependent drop, and in the circuit I see no need for a higher voltage than output voltage. A 7805 has a pass-NPN-transistor-darlington-pair, whcich has a more-or-less contant drop of 2 * Vbe plus the drop over the feeding constant current source.

Answer (score 5):

Most voltage regulators will require a voltage of 1.2 to 1.3 above the regulated output voltage. The parameter you want to look for in the datasheet is called the **dropout** voltage (\$V_{DROP}\$ or \$V_{D}\$). That amount, added to the regulated output, is the minimum input. Anything below \$V_{O}\$ + \$V_{DROP}\$ will "drop out" and fail to regulate.

Your datasheet (page 9) shows \$V_{D}\$ of 2 typical, 2.5 max. That means you should be between 7 and 7.5 volts input to attain a constant 5V output.

Comment: Plus a few percent if you want good voltage regulation (less ripple). E.g. if the regulator specifies output voltage regulation of +/- 3%, then I would say Vin >= Vo + 3% + Vdrop

Answer (score 2):

It is clearly stated on Vd, *dropout voltage* on the first page of section 5, *Electrical Characteristics*.