# DC-DC 12V converter using switching voltage regulators: heatsink dimensioning and board design

Tags: voltage-regulator

To replace [my overheating linear regulator DC-DC converter](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/92937/29792), I've designed this new board. This time I used a couple of switching 12V regulators ([LM2575-12V](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm1575.pdf)). I'm using two 1 amp regulators because my local supplier doesn't have a 2 amp version.

Here are the schematics.

[image: schematics]

Here's the board.

[image: board]

There are no pictures of the board because it doesn't exist yet. This time, I did the math first and didn't blindly built the thing.

The red arrows highlight the single-point grounding I tried to make, as recommended in the datasheet. **Is that design correct?**.

Here is my math for calculating the temperature rise from ambient temperature. According to the [LM2575 datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm1575.pdf), the power dissipation is calculated as follows:

$$PowerDissipated = V_{in} .I_q + (V_o/V_{in}).I_{load}.V_{sat}$$
$$V_o = 12V, V_{in} = 18V, V_{sat} = 1.4V, I_q = 10mA, I_{load} = 1A $$
$$PowerDissipated = 0.18W + 0.93W = 1.11W$$

Again, from the [LM2575 datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm1575.pdf), its termal resistance (junction to ambient, in worst case) is `65°C/W`, which would keep the regulators just below `100°C` considering a ambient temperature of `25°C`. If I use my [heatsinks](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/93049/29792) with `20°C/W` and the regulator thermal resistance (junction to case) of `2°`, that would keep the regulators under `50°C`

My questions are:

**1. Is my heat dissipation calculations correct?**

**2. Is my board designed correctly, especially regarding the required single-point grounding for the regulator pins?** These points are marked by the red arrows on the board image.

Comment: You are going to overdesign your board (not a bad thing) if you take that 65 C/W number. That is junction to ambient only. Your real world will be a bit better. With heat sinks, you need to use both your heatsink thermal resistance PLUS your junction to case. Not a big difference but real nonetheless. If you put a bit thicker trace around your pins, you'll begin approaching that 45 number.

Comment: That 65 C/W is for a socket without no pcb heatsinking copper. Look at notes 8 - 11 on page 7 of the pdf. Also, TI has the Switchers made Simple software here: http://www.ti.com/ww/en/simple_switcher_dc_dc_converters/index.html?DCMP=simple_switcher&HQS=switcher that can help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That 65 C/W is for a SOCKET without no pcb heatsinking copper. If soldered, with appropriate copper layout, it goes down to 45°C/W, or less, Junction to Ambient.

As for your heatsinks, they are ~20°C/W, but you forgot to add the Junction to Case rating of 2°C/W. So 25 Ambient + 20 Heatsink + 2 Junction to Case = 47°C/W * 1.2W = 56.4°C Junction Temperature.

Key points, Look at notes 8 - 11 on page 7 of the pdf, and consider the board layout (**you have tons of empty board spacing** no need to have everything so close together).

Page 19 also has good information:

> HEAT SINK/THERMAL CONSIDERATIONS
>   **In many cases, no heat sink is required to keep the LM2575 junction temperature within the allowed operating range.** For each application, to determine whether or not a heat sink will be required, the following must be identified:
>   1. Maximum ambient temperature (in the application).
>   2. Maximum regulator power dissipation (in application).
>   3. Maximum allowed junction temperature (150°C for the LM1575 or 125°C for the LM2575). For a safe, conservative design, a temperature approximately 15°C cooler than the maximum temperature should be selected.
>   4. LM2575 package thermal resistances θJA and θJC.

But then you realize, `The LM2575 is characterized for operation over the virtual junction temperature range of -40°C to 125°C`. At 1.2W (I'm rounding up a bit) and worst case 65°C/W Junction to Ambient, that's still only 78°C Junction Temperature. Almost 50°C below it's maximum operating temperature. Worst case, socket, no proper pcb copper sizing, no heatsink, and you're still good to go. ** Rearrange the traces, and throw on your heatsink, and you're golden. You might need to move the L1/L2 inductors or the heatsink won't attach right. Ideally, you would have the Ground Pin 3 connected directly to the large ground plane.**

Just bare in mind, I hope you have selected the right layout for the 2575 you are getting, as it has multiple versions.

Finally, TI has the Switchers made Simple software here: http://www.ti.com/ww/en/simple_switcher_dc_dc_converters/index.html?DCMP=simple_switcher&HQS=switcher that can help (Though the LM2575 is not included). Also, this article http://store.curiousinventor.com/blog/pcb-as-a-heat-sink-calculating-trace-width-for-given-current can help give you some ideas.

Comment: Excelent! Thanks for your answer. But what about the single-point grouding? I've updated the image to show where they are (look for the red arrows).

Comment: @Ricardo Updated the answer, and yea, that single ground point is fine, but try adjusting the layout so you can connect Pin 3 to the large ground plane, then worry about the single ground point. You don't have a large/heavily populated pcb with lots of vias, so it's not really that high of a concern.