# When a Heatsink Require on MOSFET

Tags: heatsink

How can we know weather a Component ( for example MOSFET) need A Heat sink to Work properly.

Comment: We calculate it

Comment: http://www.mcmanis.com/chuck/robotics/projects/esc2/FET-power.html

Comment: Engineers posess the magical powers of doing calculations which they can use to answer such a question.

Comment: I don't think this question deserves sarky answers. It's a big field but that's no reason folk should think it illegitimate to ask for an introduction to it.

Comment: @Dan: It's a rather broad and vague question, which doesn't work on this site.  The right way to do this here is to ask about a specific case and give real numbers.  However, I'm sure I've answered that a few times before, so would likely be closed as a duplicate.

Comment: Here is just one case where I've gone thru the calculations: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/92937/4512.

Answer (score 2):

We calculate the power dissipation, then look in the datasheet to see how hot the die without a heatsink, and compare that to the maximum operational die temperature.  If the former exceeds the latter, then a heatsink is needed.

Comment: Actually, if the former is close to the latter a heat sink will probably save a lot of grief.